# dojox.mobile back behaviour

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a view that inherits dojox.mobile.View that contains this template:

```
<div>
    <div id="listId" data-dojo-type="widgets.myproj.SomeList" data-dojo-attach-point="mylist">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Hits</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="summary" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-attach-point="summaryView">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Hitlist" movetTo: "listId">Some heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

`widgets.myproj.SomeList`  pupulates itself with  ListItems. Each ListItem has a moveTo property set to the view with `id="summary"`.

Problem is that the back behaviour here makes the browser go back in history. I only want it to behave according to the code, `back="Hitlist" movetTo: "listId"`. I.e. I want it to activate the `widgets.myproj.SomeList` widget again. (that also inherits dojox.mobile.View)

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains "movetTo" while this should be "moveTo". Is this just a typo here, or is it the same in your actual code? 
The second point is that the "back" and "moveTo" are widget properties which should be set in markup using the data-dojo-props attribute:

```
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
  data-dojo-props="back:'Hitlist', moveTo: 'listId'">Some heading</h1>
```

At a quick testing, fixing these 2 issues makes it work as expected.

Hope this helps,

Adrian

Comment: Your comments are correct - thank you! moveTo is just a typo but that did the trick. I actually always use data-dojo-props but sometimes you try tweaking in all possible directions in order to make it work. But I guess I had the same 'typo'-error in that construct and cut'n paste kept it. Anyways, thank you!